# How to deal with fat jar dependency

Tags: java, maven, dependency-management

I have a proprietary dependency that I use in my project that I can not refuse. It was built in one big fat jar with all dependent packages collected inside. By all I mean even common ones like slf4j-api, apache-commons, javax packages, etc.

Using it together with my own list of declared dependecies is risky because there's always a race in classloader on which class will be loaded first - mine or outdated class inside fat jar.

I was wondering is there a way around this problem? How to treat such fat jars? I'm using maven for dependency management.

Comment: Blame those people cause a fat jar with such content does not really make sense (commons etc.). This will always cause classloading problems. So you have to maintain a self constructed jar....otherwise you are lost...

Comment: @khmarbaise Oh, I'm blaming them every day, but its not helping. They'll not do anything about their package distribution. Certainly not in the near future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that there's another way. I can wrap this library jar in its own custom classloader

```
URLClassLoader c1 = new URLClassLoader(new Url[] { new URL("file:lib/fatJarDep.jar"});
```

and create a factory that will instantiate classes of this library using this isolated classloader

```
Class.forName("className", true, c1);
```

Answer (score 3):

In Maven, the order in which you define dependencies in your POM is significant.
If you list them in the correct order, they should be added to the jar in that order,
and whichever class is higher in the file, that's the one that will get loaded first.

If you will compose your runtime classpath out of multiple jars,
then again, it's a matter of putting the jars in the right order.

Comment: This will not fix an issue: depending on what class will be loaded first, you'll get ethier your code glitching or code of this library. Because of prossible class incompatibility. (Versions of libraries inside fat jar are unknown)

Comment: Old question, but I need to express here, that one should avoid as much as possible to rely on the order of the JARs in the classpath. This leads to additional complexity and new failure modes. I had this already in the past, where a legacy project used JAR ordering as kind of plugin mechanism. If the order is messed up, the whole software behaved differently...

Answer (score 2):

If you know that some functionalities of the fat jar will work when you exclude some fo their dependencies or you want to include them yourself, you can try this:

1. Make a maven project that depends on the fat jar only
2. Use [maven-shade-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/), in particular it's relocation feature to exclude packages you don't want, or to just relocate all the jar's classes into another package, and thus move them out of the way.
3. Use the project's artifact instead of fat propietary jar in your other project.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I didn't knew about maven shade plugin, I'll try it.

Answer (score 0):

If the jar has all dependency class extracted inside you can't exclude them from classloading, so same dependecy in your project may conflict.

You should edit the fat jar and manually remove the classes to make a light version, then install it in your repo and refer to it in your pom.

Comment: I don't wan't to take resposibility of supporting a third party project. Making custom build of this library will cost me time to backport patches and new releases from main source.

Comment: You can write a simple procedure that make the thin jar that you run at version update. I suppose you manually update the pom on new jar release, the procedure can take in input the new version, make the thin jar and update your pom

Comment: Can you guide me on such simple procedure? Show some examples or articles about creating it?